# Beamer \animategraphics Missing $ inserted \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, animate

I am using the animate package to make some nice animations from several pdfs created in R. I have 3 animations in my beamer presentation, but now I'm trying to insert the forth and I get the error:

```
Missing $ inserted \end{frame}.
```

If I replace such new animation with other it works. The code I'm using is

```
\begin{frame}{Deaths 1997-2013}
  \centerline{\animategraphics[controls,buttonsize=0.3cm,width=7.5cm]{5}{"AP_inc_"}{1997}{2013}}
\end{frame}
```

and just with this set of pdfs the error appears. Can somebody help me.

Comment: Just a guess `AP_inc_` looks suspicious. Try to get rid of underscores by renaming the file.

Comment: Thanks I changed the name of the pdfs but now the error is: Argument of \@tempc has an extra } \end{frame}

Comment: try `\usepackage{grffile}`

Comment: No error here after removing the quotes `"..."`. Please prepare a minimal compilable example.

Comment: @AlexG Care for an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file basename (file name `AP_inc_????.pdf` without frame number and extension) has to be specified without quotes:

```
\animategraphics[controls,buttonsize=0.3cm,width=7.5cm]{5}{AP_inc_}{1997}{2013}
```